# User pool does not exist

Tags: java, server-side, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to connect to aws cognito from a java backend, but when it comes to testing it inside AWS Lambda, it throws me an exception with the following message:

```
"errorMessage": "User pool XXXXX does not exist. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: -------------)"
```

The credentials that I have entered are correct, because I have tested them in a python code and it works correctly.

this is the code with which I made the connection:

```
private AdminInitiateAuthRequest buildAuhtRequest(String email, String password){
    Map<String,String> authParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
    authParams.put("email", email);
    authParams.put("password", password);

    return new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
            .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)
            .withAuthParameters(authParams)
            .withClientId(credentials.getClientId())
            .withUserPoolId(credentials.getPoolId());
}
```

and this is the class of credentials, although it is super simple:

```
public class CognitoClientCredentials {

    private String poolId = "xxxxxxxxx";
    private String clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    public String getPoolId(){
        return this.poolId;
    }

    public String getClientId(){
        return this.clientId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for someone who could be having an user pool related error. Such error started to appear to me after I changed the verification type from 'code' to 'link' in AWS Cognito. The issue got solved by just setting up a domain name in the 'App Integration' tab in my user pool settings.
This thread helped me to solve my issue -> https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/512
[image]

Comment: I had the same issue because i switched from verification code to link, and this solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that locally you have already setup the aws environment with a default region, access key and access secret; while you lambda role is not authorizes to handle that Cognito Pool that you are specifying. Try to augment the permissions of you lambda role.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your answer 

Answer (score 1):

Set the region and try so your function identify which region to check under the cognito.

Answer (score 0):

What happened to me was...

the AWS.Config grabbed my profile from my Windows 10 user account (.aws/credentials).

So, programatically I had to modify the AWS.config.credentials

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple AWS profiles setup, so I had to change my default one to be the  AWS instance I wanted to connect to and that worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).